# CSS Stacked icons - Icons are stacking on top of other icons

Tags: html, css

I'm creating some [stack icons](http://stackicons.com/) and all the threads I've read so far asks you to do something like this -

```css
 i {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    i:before {
        content: "\f099";
        position: absolute; 
        font-size: 1.5em;   
    }
    
    i:after {
        content: "\f096";
        position: absolute; 
        font-size: 2.1em;
        left: 0;    
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa"></i>
```

The problem I have with this is that when you have multiple icons,

```
<i class="fa"></i>
<i class="fa"></i>
```

Both icons will stack on top of each other.

This solved it,

```css
i {
            position: relative;
        }
        
        i:before {
            content: "\f099";
            font-size: 1.5em;   
        }
        
        i:after {
            content: "\f096";
            position: absolute; 
            font-size: 2.1em;
            left: 0;    
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa"></i>
```

What I did was remove the `position: absolute` from the `i:before` and leave `position:absolute` and `left:0` in `i:after` and the icons are working perfectly fine.

What I want to know is whether my solution is correct and why did the other solutions have a `position:absolute` in `i:before`?

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` isn't needed in `i:before` because `:before` is render before the element and with take the position of this one.

When you added the `position:absolute` to `i:before`, the width and height of the `i` tag were equals to 0px because it considers there is no element inside of the tag (an effect of `position:absolute`).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably for the hover effect.

```css
i {
  position: relative;
}

i:before {
  content: "\f099";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

i:after {
  content: "\f096";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  left: 0;
}

i.hideThis {
  color: orange;
  opacity: 0;
}

.foo i {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.foo:hover i.hoverThis {
  opacity: 0;
}

.foo:hover i.hideThis {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="foo">
  <i class="fa hideThis"></i><i class="fa hoverThis"></i>
</div>
```